# Dataframe.rolling().mean not calculating moving average

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I've been trying to calculate a moving avarage using pandas, but when I use the Dataframe.rolling().mean(), it copies the value instead.

```
stock_info['stock'].head()
```

```
    Fecha               Open        High        Low         Close       Volume
0   04-05-2007 00:00:00 234,4593    255,5703    234,3532    246,8906    6044574
1   07-05-2007 00:00:00 246,8906    254,7023    247,855     252,1563    2953869
2   08-05-2007 00:00:00 252,1562    250,7482    244,9617    250,1695    2007217
3   09-05-2007 00:00:00 250,1695    249,7838    245,9261    248,3757    2329078
4   10-05-2007 00:00:00 248,8194    248,9158    244,9617    245,6368    2138002
```

```
stock_info['stock']['MA'] = stock_info['stock']['Close'].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

```
    Fecha               Open        High        Low         Close       Volume  MA
0   04-05-2007 00:00:00 234,4593    255,5703    234,3532    246,8906    6044574 246,8906
1   07-05-2007 00:00:00 246,8906    254,7023    247,855     252,1563    2953869 252,1563
2   08-05-2007 00:00:00 252,1562    250,7482    244,9617    250,1695    2007217 250,1695
3   09-05-2007 00:00:00 250,1695    249,7838    245,9261    248,3757    2329078 248,3757
4   10-05-2007 00:00:00 248,8194    248,9158    244,9617    245,6368    2138002 245,6368
```

Comment: What's the `dtype` of your `Close` column? From the comma separator, I suspect that you might have strings rather than numbers.

Comment: You are right, that was the damn problem, so numb. The data came from an csv file and when I set decimal= ',' it worked seamlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thought is that the values in `stock_info['stock']['Close']` are stored as strings, rather than as a numeric type. Attempting

```
df['MA'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

on

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Close': ['246,8906', '252,1563', '250,1695']})
```

gives

```
  df
Out[38]:
      Close        MA
0  246,8906  246,8906
1  252,1563  252,1563
2  250,1695  250,1695
```

as happened for you.
Converting this to a numeric value first, say with

```
df['MA'] = df['Close'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float).rolling(window=2).mean()
```

gives

```
  df
Out[40]: 
      Close         MA
0  246,8906        NaN
1  252,1563  249.52345
2  250,1695  251.16290
```

as desired.

Comment: Exactly, that's what happened, as described by Mark comment in below my question.

Answer (score 0):

According to Pandas Latest version docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html you have tu use the ***`on`*** parameter in the `rolling` function.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'val': range(10,30)})
df1['avg'] = df1.val.mean()
df1['rolling'] =  df1.rolling(window=2, on='avg').mean()
```

instead of using `df1['avg'].rolling()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use pd.rolling_mean to calcualte

example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([ np.random.randint(-10,10) for _ in xrange(100) ],columns =['val'])
   val
0    4
1   -3
2   -7
3    3
4  -10
df1['MA'] = pd.rolling_mean(df1.val,2)
   val   MA
0    4  NaN
1   -3  0.5
2   -7 -5.0
3    3 -2.0
4  -10 -3.5
```